# Selecting the popular posts using three tables

Tags: mysql

I have three tables:

1. posts - contains the posts by users,
2. post_reviews - contains the likes on the posts, and
3. post_share - contains the post id and user id of that which is shared.

I would like to select five popular posts using these three tables. The popular posts are those that have the highest no of reviews and shares. I am finding it really hard to construct a SQL query for this.

A slight help or guidance in this matter will be highly appreciated.

UPDATE:

The table structure is as follows:

```
table posts{

id - PK
uid - FK
post - text
}

table post_reviews{

id - PK
pid - FK (Post Id)
uid - FK
like_unlike - ENUM
}

table post_share{

id - PK
pid - FK (Post Id)
uid - FK
}
```

Comment: Please supply more information. Run these `SHOW CREATE TABLE posts\G`, `SHOW CREATE TABLE posts_reviews\G` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE posts_share\G` and post their output in the question.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA - Updated question with the table structures.

Answer (score 1):

5 Most Popular Posts By Reviews

```
SELECT A.uid,B.post_count reviews,A.post
FROM posts A LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT * FROM
    (
        SELECT pid,COUNT(1) post_count
        FROM post_reviews
        GROUP BY pid
        ORDER BY post_count DESC
    ) AA LIMIT 5
) B
ON A.id = B.pid;
```

5 Most Popular Posts By Shares

```
SELECT A.uid,B.post_count shares,A.post
FROM posts A LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT * FROM
    (
        SELECT pid,COUNT(1) post_count
        FROM post_shares
        GROUP BY pid
        ORDER BY post_count DESC
    ) AA LIMIT 5
) B
ON A.id = B.pid;
```

I hope this gives you a start...

Comment: @RonaldoMySQLDBA - Thank you for the effort. I will start with this.

Comment: There was a syntax error I saw. I corrected it.